# Take today's date and roll it back to the last instance of a particular month/day

Tags: sql-server, date, date-arithmetic

I want to select all dates between January 1st, 2000 and the last September 30th based on today's date. In this case, because today is September 6th, 2019, it would return all dates between January 1st, 2000 and September 30th, 2018.

I know that I need to do something like

> Date between '01-JAN-00' and some calculation on `GETDATE()`

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE t
WHERE t.Date BETWEEN '01-JAN-00' and GETDATE()
```

Comment: If today were September 30th, what year would you expect it to use?

Comment: the previous year. it should only switch to the current year on october 1st.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get all the data between two dates:

1. startDate = 1-Jan-2000
2. endDate = truncMonth(currentDate) - 1year + daysInCurrentMonth

MySql has the `DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr unit), DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL expr unit)` function, which you can find [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add), and the truncation functions by [Ollie](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/)

The `now()` function gets the current system dateTime.

The "daysInCurrentMonth" you should be able to work out fairly easily.

ANd, you should be able to then construct user-defined variables with those functions, and pass them as predicates to the `where ...` part of your query, eg `... where t.Date >= @startDate and t.Date <= @endDate`

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention that I am using SQL Server and not MY SQL syntax.

I would need to take the dates between Jan 1, 2000 and the last September 30th prior to today's date. If it were to run today, it would pull all dates between Jan 1, 2000 and September 30th, 2018. If it were to run on October 1st, 2019, then it would pull all dates between Jan 1, 2000 and September 30th, 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Example of how this can be written. You can alter the @Today value to test the logic.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Dt DATE)
INSERT INTO @t SELECT '01/01/2000'
INSERT INTO @t SELECT '09/29/2018'
INSERT INTO @t SELECT '09/30/2018'
INSERT INTO @t SELECT '10/01/2018'
INSERT INTO @t SELECT '09/29/2019'
INSERT INTO @t SELECT '09/30/2019'
INSERT INTO @t SELECT '10/01/2019'

DECLARE @Today DATE= '10/01/2019'--GETDATE()

SELECT *
FROM @t
WHERE dt>='01/01/2000'
AND dt<=
    CASE
        WHEN (DATEPART(MONTH,@Today)<=9 AND DATEPART(DAY,@Today)<=30) THEN
            '09/30/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DATEPART(YEAR,@Today)-1)
        ELSE
            '09/30/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),DATEPART(YEAR,@Today))
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a CASE statement in which you build the date using the year from GETDATE(). Sample code follows

```
SELECT * 
FROM T 
WHERE [DATE] > '2000-01-01' 
    and [DATE] < CASE WHEN GETDATE() < DATEFROMPARTS (YEAR(GETDATE()),9,30)
        --If we're before Sept 30 of this year
        THEN DATEFROMPARTS (YEAR(GETDATE())-1,9,30) --Last Sept 30
        ELSE DATEFROMPARTS (YEAR(GETDATE()),9,30) END --This Sept 30
ORDER BY [DATE]
```

Comment: I would just say `when month(getdate()) < 10` And you need to adjust for the comment above regarding Sept 30.

Comment: Good point, Shawnt00, that's clearer and more efficient, the only reason I'm not changing my code to use this is he didn't specify the boundary condition of running it *on* Sept 30, the DateFromParts solution can easily be adapted to go either way by changing between "<" and "<=", while the month(getdate()) cannot easily switch between. But great comment, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you like concise expressions:

```
eomonth(dateadd(month, (month(dt) / 10) * 12 - month(dt) - 3, dt)
```

https://rextester.com/CMW32190